# How to access bucket data in VM instance - Google ML Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-ml, gsutil

I am a beginner on Google ML Cloud.

Goal : Read data in jupyter notebook on VM instance and use that data to run CNN algorithm.

Created a bucket and uploaded data in that bucket in below format.

- Dataset/Train/Dogs/*multiple dogs images for training*
- Dataset/Train/Cats/*multiple cats images for training*
- Dataset/Test/Dogs/*multiple dogs images for testing*
- Dataset/Test/Cats/*multiple cats images for testing*

I want to read these images in jupyter notebook which is installed on VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow, just use filenames of the form gs://bucket/.. if you need wildcard matching, use tf.glob

If you need more help, post code